# What is the technical name of the electric window dimming system?

Tags: windows, boeing-787

I have recently flown from Mexico City (MMMX) to Tokyo, Japan (RJAA) in a Boeing 787 of All Nipon Airways (ANA).

The plane had an electric system for dimming the windows.

Does the window-dimming system have a technical name?

Comment: Related: [Electrochromic interactive panel](http://www.gentex.com/aerospace/aircraft-windows), probably liquid-crystal gel.

Answer (score 5):

From a Boeing [article](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_4_06/article_04_4.html):

> Electro-chromatic dimmable windows

It's generically described in the article as being an electronically controlled and can dim or lighten the cabin at the push of a button. They claim 70k cycles or 20 years of service

[Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/5829395/how-boeings-magical-787-dreamliner-windows-work) provides a succinct description of it's operation

> The dimming effect is the result of an electrified gel sandwiched between two thin pieces of glass. As the electric current increases, the gel darkens and as it drops, the gel lightens.

The maker appears to be Gentex and they have a variety of electric dimming window patents but it's not clear which one is used in the 787

Answer (score 2):

Boeing's patent [US20050200934 A1](http://www.google.co.in/patents/US20050200934) calls such a system 'Electrochromic device control system'. From the patent:

> Electrochromic device control systems and methods are disclosed. ... Each transparent window has an electrochromic device operatively associated therewith. ... In one particular embodiment, a window dimming control system in accordance with the present invention may advantageously be incorporated into an existing cabin services system of a passenger aircraft.

Comment: oooo! thanks :D